# How to run SpecFlow tests in parallel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mstest, specflow

I try to run SpecFlow tests with NUnit test runner in parallel. I am using:

- C# / .Net Core 3.1
- NUnit as testrunner
- Specflow

I have added this line on top of a file (as describe here: https://specflow.org/documentation/parallel-execution/):

```
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
```

Tests start to execute in parallel but immediately throw an error:

```
Message: 
    System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added. Key: NUnitTestProject1.SpecFlowFeature1Steps
Stack Trace: 
    Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
    Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    TypeRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
    ObjectContainer.ResolveObject(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath)
    ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, ResolutionList resolutionPath, String name)
    ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, String name)
    TestObjectResolver.ResolveBindingInstance(Type bindingType, IObjectContainer container)
    lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , Int32 )
    BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
    TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
    TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
    TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
    TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
    SpecFlowFeature1Feature.ScenarioCleanup()
    SpecFlowFeature1Feature.AddTwoNumbers() line 8
```

I tried without SpecFlow (just raw NUnit) and it worked. I also tried with MSTest test runner but got the same exception.

I have made a very tiny example project which you can clone here: https://github.com/davidguidali/specflowerror

Any help would be appreciated. :)

EDIT: Full code of steps

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]

namespace NUnitTestProject1
{
    [Binding]
    public class SpecFlowFeature1Steps
    {
        [Given(@"test(.*)")]
        public void GivenTest(int p0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in SpecFlowFeature1Steps

Comment: Maybe this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554172/way-to-run-nunit-tests-within-class-in-parallel-but-not-run-with-other-class-te) can help you

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Execution/Parallel-Execution.html#parallel-scheduling-unit), the SpecFlow+ Runner supports Scenario parallelism. The NUnit, MsTest, xUnit runners only support Feature parallelism.

I noticed you are using NUnit. It is also documented under [NUnit configuration](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Execution/Parallel-Execution.html#nunit-configuration): *"Note: SpecFlow does not support scenario level parallelization with NUnit (when scenarios from the same feature execute in parallel). If you configure a higher level NUnit parallelization than “Fixtures” your tests will fail with runtime errors."*

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

Comment: Thats not what I want. I want to run all the tests in parallel. ParallelScope.Fixtures only runs tests as per feature (class) in parallel. I want to run them also as per Scenario (method).

Comment: You can run SpecFlow tests only in this parallel mode. Scenarios in one Feature are executed one by one. As for non-specFlow tests from one class: yes, they can run in parallel.

Comment: Is there any official source for this? I couldn't find anything. Why is this the case? Is it the same for MSTest(s)?

Comment: Check here: https://specflow.org/documentation/parallel-execution/

Comment: its nowehere written that execution on method level does not work.

Comment: See also https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1535

Answer (score 0):

You should create new class usings.cs with

```
global using NUnit.Framework;
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] // Set on parallel
[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(13)] // Count of threads
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).